# How are the following questions duplicate of each other? Wrongly flagged as Duplicate

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates

1. [Did Lord Vishnu rape tulsi in her previous birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24565/did-lord-vishnu-rape-tulsi-in-her-previous-birth)

This above question is marked Duplicate of this question-
2. [Vishnu seducing Jalandhar's wife Vrinda: an act of injustice? Why?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18757/vishnu-seducing-jalandhars-wife-vrinda-an-act-of-injustice-why)

The Q1 asks what is the story or source of story
and Q2 asks was Vishnu's act a justice

Here's **what Q1 asks** -

> 1) Is this correct or a fake story?
>   2) What is the source of this story?
>   3) Where can I find the original translation of this myth?
>   4) Is it available on sacred-texts.com?
>   Which purana or scripture is it in?

And here's **what Q2 asks** -

> Question: Jalandhara should be punished for thinking evil about Parvati, then why is vrinda punished for his misdeeds?
>   Isn't this an act of injustice?

Clearly in no manner Q1 is duplicate of Q2.

Q1 should be reopened.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Ok. I will reopen it. Looks like you asked me with other account which i was not notified.